# animate slogan text on homepage

Tags: jquery, animation

Does anyone how to make an animation like:

http://www.silverstripe.org/software/

The text fades and scrolls parallax so it seems with the background.

I have investigated several jQuery animation tools but they don't replicate his behavious

Comment: You can just use animate and fade function of jQuery

Comment: Definitely this looks like Bootstrap (jumbotron in combination with affix function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The silverstripe page is using skrollr.js. You can find more info here:

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/